# React js State not being set on forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First am pretty new to react.
Am trying to change state of form inputs as follows

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pwd:'',
        email:'',
        value:''
    };
    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
}
handlePasswordChange(event){
    //this.setState({value: event.target.value});//Works
    this.setState({pwd: event.target.pwd});// Fails 
}
```

My problem is I am not able to set the state of the password field and instead am getting a warning saying `Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type password to be uncontrolled`
My render method is as bellow

```
 render(){
    return(
        <div
        className="container col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"
        >
      <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup
          controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
              <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                  Email
              </Col>
              <Col sm={10}>
                  <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Email"
                               value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange}/>
              </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup
              controlId="formHorizontalPassword"
              >
                  <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                      Password
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={10}>
                      <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password"
                                   value={this.state.pwd} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
                          //if I change to value={this.state.value} it works
                      />
                  </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
              <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                  <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
              </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
              <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                  <Button type="submit">
                      Sign in
                  </Button>
              </Col>
          </FormGroup>
      </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Note:** I have omitted some code that I think is not crucial.

Comment: What it contain `event.targer.pwd` ?

Comment: @SagarJajoriya nothing because it's not a valid attribute of a HTML `node`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change:

```
this.setState({pwd: event.target.pwd});// Fails
```

for:

```
this.setState({pwd: event.target.value});
```

The event has an attribute `target` which has an attribute `value` with the value of the field at that particular moment. Hence you should assign that value to the `pwd` state attribute that you are defining :)

Always remember that you are sending an object to the setState function. The key of that object is the one that you are defining (`pwd`). The value is just the thing that you assign to that key, it could be a number, a string... or the value of an object's attribute (like in this case the string that contains `event.target.value`).

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you a little snippet that I'm using in production:

This is your state:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    pwd:'',
    email:''
};
```

So, now you may want to build a form in order to change these values. I'd recommend to do so:

```
<input name="pwd" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} ...>
<input name="email" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} ...>
```

So now you can do so:

```
handleChange(e){
 this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

`e.target.name` takes the name of your input field (in that case: 'pwd' or 'email') and `e.target.value` takes its value.

When you're writing more complex forms, this can help you a lot!